# Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty warning message?

Tags: php, warnings, getimagesize

Up until recently I've been using some PHP to upload photos to a site. But suddenly it's started triggering all sorts of error messages.

I use a form that on action runs the following code:

```
$uploaddir = "../../user_content/photo/";
$allowed_ext = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   
        $info = getimagesize($file_temp);
    } else {
        print "File not sent to server succesfully!";
        exit;
    }
```

The file upload part of the form has the following elements:

```
<input name="file" type="file" class="photo_file_upload">
```

The submit button for uploading has the following attributes:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="photo_upload">Upload</button>
```

But whenever I run this, I always get the following warning:

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in (upload PHP file) on line 10
```

(line 10 is this part: $info = getimagesize($file_temp);)

Anyone have any ideas on what the cause of this is?

Comment: What does your `<form>` look like?

Comment: Did you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form attributes?

Comment: As far as I recall `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is just the filename without a path, you should use `move_uploaded_file()` then run `getimagesize()` on the filename including the path where you moved it. I could be wrong though.

Comment: You are wrong. tmp_name has the temporary filename on the server. And how would you move the file if you do not know the path, but only the filename?

Comment: The form uses enctype="multipart/form-data" and gets through this check: if(isset($_POST["submit"])); so I assume it's being submitted correctly? In which case the issue is with my PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You checked if the form was submitted, but didn't check if the file was sent. In some cases, a form could be submitted but the file will not sent (i.e. file size is bigger then file size limit in config).

Use this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   
    $info = getimagesize($file_temp);
} else {
    print "File not sent to server succesfully!";
    exit;
}
```

You see **&& isset($_FILES['file'])** is new

Or you can extend it

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   
    $info = getimagesize($file_temp);
} 
elseif(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    print "Form was submitted but file wasn't send";
    exit;
}
else {
    print "Form wasn't submitted!";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably use isset() twice.

Comment: I'm newcommer on stackoverflow, so tell me why/who my code was changed, i don't think that `&&` instead of `AND` is better

Comment: and use `isset($_FILES['file'])` is bad way. because `if ($_FILES['file'])` AND `if(isset($_FILES['file']))` returns different results! because `$_FILES['file']` array is sent by form but it's empty. so `isset()` will return true. but we need to check if array empty, thats why we can use `if($_FILES['file'])` OR `if(empty($_FILES['file']))` but not `isset()`

Comment: Please elaborate. I assume that $_FILES['file'] does not exist if the form is technically wrong. That's what `isset()` checks for. You assume that $_FILES['file'] can be evaluated to a boolean. This is only true if it exists (my check), and will otherwise trigger a NOTICE (bad thing). Regarding your logic operator: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php especially the last two demos in example 1. "&&" usually behaves like you would expect.

Comment: See: If the form is sent correctly, but the upload fails for some reason, $_FILES['file'] is NOT empty, but at least has $_FILES['file']['error']. Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php My suggestion does not check errors either, but at least I check if the upload from the form worked without throwing notices. Code should always run without them, they are a valuable source for typo detection - and drain performance as well.

Comment: looks like you are right, `isset()` will work fine, i will update my answer. But `AND`, `&&` it's not exactly the same. `AND` has lower priority against `&&`. anyway thanks for discussion

Comment: Ok, I tried the checks you mentioned decss (the extended one with the minor typo corrected just before the last else statement); but I'm still getting the same error message. :/

Comment: Ok, I got it working. The final issue was a typo on my end, thanks for the help @decss!

Answer (score 5):

Change these parameters in your php.ini file; (Currently it allow only 2Mb size to 
 upload and post). Sometimes it's reason for these errors.

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
max_execution_time = 120
```

Answer (score 2):

Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in

Verify the MAX_SIZE variable,
example to define it for a 2Mo image:

```html
define('MAX_SIZE', 2000000);
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MAX_SIZE; ?>" /> 
<input name="fichier" type="file" id="fichier_a_uploader" /> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Uploader" /> 
</form>
```

you can also verify the Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept and Maximum allowed size for uploaded files in PHP.ini :
post_max_size = ?
upload_max_filesize = ?

Answer (score 1):

After you upgrade 'upload-max-filesize' , Restart all Services of wamp or xampp ! it will right !

Answer (score 0):

you should change the form enctype to "multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     ....
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in D:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\php\form_php\application\process_application.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in D:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\php\form_php\application\process_application.php on line 43

Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in D:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\php\form_php\application\process_application.php on line 43
File is not an image.Sorry, file already exists.
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in D:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\php\form_php\application\process_application.php on line 58
Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

If You Get Errors like this one you should check you have added form enctype to "multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     ....
</form>
```

Use to catch me out quite a lot to begin with.