# Image uploading error in PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading, getimagesize

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Above is my HTML code. Following is my upload PHP code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

When I upload an image it returns the following:

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\wamp64\www\company\test\upload.php on line 8

*File is not an image.*

Is there anything wrong with the code?
I am using PHP v5.6.16, please help me.

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
```

is empty but,

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

is not empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: getimagesize() \[function.getimagesize\]: Filename cannot be empty warning message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043892/warning-getimagesize-function-getimagesize-filename-cannot-be-empty-warnin)

Comment: I looked into that question. but the thing is $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] is empty. but $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] is not empty. why is that??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
    $file_temp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];   
    $info = getimagesize($file_temp);
    if($info !== false) {
       echo "File is an image - " . $info["mime"] . ".";
       $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
       echo "File is not an image.";
       $uploadOk = 0;
    }
} 
else if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
    print "Form was submitted but file wasn't send";
    exit;
}
else {
    print "Form wasn't submitted!";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I did according to your answer.. the thing is $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] is empty, but $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] not empty. why is that??

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `$_FILES` is not empty using [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) {
     // do your stuff
}
```

OR just check key exist and not `null` using [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I did according to your answer.. the thing is $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] is empty, but $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] not empty. why is that??

Comment: Check this links:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472741/files-field-tmp-name-has-no-value-on-jpg-file-extension and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358737/php-file-upload-error-tmp-name-is-empty