# getimagesize() function doesn't work for 5K images?

Tags: php, image, function, size, getimagesize

Guys check out this gif. 
https://gfycat.com/IllustriousThirdLamb

I'll wait for your solutions.

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $img = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
    $size = $_FILES["img"]["size"];
    $getRes = getimagesize($img);
    echo "Image height : ".$getRes[0]."px<br>";
    echo "Image width : ".$getRes[1]."px<br>";
}
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED. THANKS**

Comment: What's your php code?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your next experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043892/warning-getimagesize-function-getimagesize-filename-cannot-be-empty-warnin) `In some cases, a form could be submitted but the file will not sent (i.e. file size is bigger then file size limit in config).` We need to see your code

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Its a good idea to check `$_FILES["img"]['error']` before assuming the file has successfully uploaded

Comment: Did you please post your error too

Comment: @SivaGanesh you can see the error in the gif file. check out the link

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase PHP's memory limit

```
php_value memory_limit 16M 
ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');
```

Comment: I think it's not about that. I already change it. and also when I select 1 MB images it's still shows error.

Comment: What did yo change it too?

Comment: I have change file limit value in xampp.

Comment: @Functionalition You can do so in your .htaccess 
php_value memory_limit 16M

Answer (score 0):

Check your upload limit. The file might be larger than your php upload limit, causing the uploaded file to be non-existant.

In your php.ini modify the following variables

```
upload_max_filesize = 12M
post_max_size = 12M
```

You might have to increase memory_limit too, but I think it would be upload to be the main culprit here.

Turn on error reporting to see what errors are reported

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: what's the filesize of that image you're uploading? @Functionalition

Comment: I think it's 2.6 mB

Comment: @Functionalition I just tried to create a image with those dimensions in gimp. It says it occupies 190 mb of ram. Set your memory limit to 200mb. see if that helps.

Comment: it's solved. thanks. I forgot to do restart xampp. love you

Comment: Never change @Tschallacka that was great.